# re.compile not working for BeautifulSoup4 text element when there are children

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the following which works fine when there are no children the the `h4` tag:

```
if (BS.find('div', {"id" : "table_content"}).find('h4', text=re.compile(".*Super Users.*"))):
    print "Found Super Users!"
```

however, when the `h4` tag has children, the print never happens. I have tried debugging using the following:

```
for h4 in BS.find('div', {"id" : "table_content"}).findAll('h4'):
    print h4.text
```

which produces:

```
Users 
Super Users
    (TMP)
     

Administrators
....
```

Basically, the `(TMP)` part seems to be throwing it off because it is text from a child of the `h4` tag, like such:

```
<h4>Super User
    <span>(<a href="/tmp">TMP</a>)</span>
</h4>
```

The downside to this is that the `(TMP)` is not always there, so I cant make assumptions. I just need to know if `Super User` is in the text of `h4`, then I can continue.

Comment: not sure but wouldn't it be `re.compile(".*Super Users.*",flags=re.DOTALL)` to handle linefeeds?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work. It may be the line feeds though because I tested `if h4.text[:5] == "Super"` and it passes. Maybe my regex is off?

Comment: ok, try `re.compile(".*Super\s+Users.*"))`, all whitespaces are not spaces.

Comment: negative. This works fine when the subchildren aren't present (when the `<span>(<a href="/tmp">TMP</a>)</span>` isn't there)

Comment: a [mcve] would help others reproduce and try to find a solution for you. No real [mcve] is probably the reason noone could answer.

Comment: All of this was explained above in the question...

Comment: I can confirm, it's not working as expected. One workaround is you can loop through find_all and do the checking inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set tag type (h4) in `find` parameters or set it separately as BS's method:

```
if (BS.find('div', {"id" : "table_content"}).find(text=re.compile(".*Super Users.*"))):
    print "Found Super Users!"
```

or

```
if (BS.find('div', {"id" : "table_content"}).h4.find(text=re.compile(".*Super Users.*"))):
    print "Found Super Users!"
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution. Why does this make a difference?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that it is a feature of current parser. When you don't set tag - it will search all html elements, which have this attribute ('text').  Probably when h4 tag has siblings, parser decides that this text belongs to them, but not to parent h4 tag itself. So, when you call `find` without tags, you let it search in siblings texts too.